# Como adicionar contagem com PHP?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Quero colocar um efeito *Carousel* em uma sessão, na pagina inicial, onde eu pego os 3 posts mais recentes. Mas para isso eu preciso que o *index*, mude conforme for fazendo o *loop*.

Da forma como está, o *index* aparece `0`, para todos os posts. Ou seja, o primeiro post vai ficar com o `<slide :index="0">`, o segundo tb e o terceiro igual.  Imagino que preciso fazer uma condição com `count`, para cada vez que fizer o *loop* e pegar 1 post, mude o numero do *index* para `+1`.
O segundo post deveria ficar `<slide :index="1">`, e o terceiro com `<slide :index="2">`; como faço uma condição para o número do index aumentar +1, conforme o post é chamado no loop?

```html
<div id="carousel3d">
  <carousel-3d :perspective="0" :space="200" :display="5" :controls-visible="true" :controls-prev-html="'❬'" :controls-next-html="'❭'" :controls-width="30" :controls-height="60" :clickable="true" :autoplay="true" :autoplay-timeout="5000">
            <!--  Define our WP Query Parameters -->
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>
            <!-- Start our WP Query -->
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <!-- Display the Post Title with Hyperlink -->
        ***<slide :index="0">***
            <span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div> 
                <!-- Display the Post Excerpt -->
            <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>Veja mais</a>
        </slide> 
        <!-- Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit -->
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    <p style="text-align: center;">Conheça mais</p>
     </carousel-3d>
</div>
```

Mas não sei como fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: eu editei ela, ñ sei como posso explicar de outra forma.

Comment: antes do while $i=0;  `<slide :index="<?php echo $i ?>">` e antes do `endwhile;` coloque `$i++;`

Comment: @Bacco, vc está com algum problema para tentar entender as perguntas dos usuarios, principalmente dos novatos? O site está inundado de pendentes.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo neste caso é melhor perguntar pros usuários das pendentes se eles tem dificuldade de entender o funcionamento básico do site. Infelizmente alguém deve ter divulgado o site como um helpdesk por engano (estou falando em geral, não dessa pergunta aqui em específico). O que mais me assusta é usuários que já tem tempo aqui ainda não terem entendido, pra ser bem sincero. E olha que tem um geralmente tem um quadro amarelo explicando o que fazer para reabrir, mas não vejo muitas "tentativas" nesse sentido.

Comment: Obrigada @LeoCaracciolo

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a documentação em

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

o próprio Wordpress já tem uma propriedade específica para saber o índice do post atual:

```
<slide index="<?php echo $the_query->$current_post; ?>">
```

Ou, usando um PHP atualizado:

```
<slide index="<?=$the_query->$current_post?>">
```

Se fosse em outro contexto poderia ser algo assim:

Fora do loop: `$i = 0;`

E dentro:

```
<slide index="<?php echo ++$i; ?>">
```

Ou mesmo:

```
<slide index="<?php echo $i++; ?>">
```

se quiser usar pós-incremento.

Mas como se trata de Wordpress, já não faz tanto sentido, visto que tem a propriedade correta para a finalidade.

Comment: Ótimo, com essa resposta,  não vou precisar perguntar a AP se ela tem dificuldade de entender o funcionamento básico do site!

Comment: Eu prefiro que ela (e todos os outros usuários) entendam como o site funciona, e como se expressar bem claramente sobre os pontos que geram dúvida, pois vai facilitar pra todo mundo, e ajuda a obter respostas mais rapidamente (e sem chutes, como costuma acontecer quando o post fica nebuloso). Mas eu me referia em especial a quem tem tempo de site e ainda não entendeu (quanto mais gente "antenada" no assunto, melhor a coisa anda). Esta edição, em especial, evidenciou melhor em qual das partes era a dificuldade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/353615/3

Comment: Eu tenho dificuldade de me expressar na vida real, imagina aqui no pc, escrevendo. E cada pessoa que lê, interpreta de uma forma diferente. De qualquer forma, se ficou nebluso ou foge as regras do site, peço desculpas, pois realmente sou nova aqui. 
O importante é que foi editado, por mim e por outros users, e ficou claro o suficiente para algumas boas almas conseguirem me entender kkk. Obrigada :)

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta completa, ainda não tive tempo de testar, pois não estou no meu pc. Mas muito obrigada pela resposta, era exatamente isso que eu queria. e simplesmente não sabia como fazer, ou me expressar. Vlw kk